# how to fix Multi-output linear regression predict the dim is not aligned in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When I try use the `sklearn.linear-regression` this error occurs:

this is my code:

```
#the dimension of data and lable for linear regression
X_test =1*688
Y_test =1*2065


X_train =501*688
Y_train =501*2065

# fit the regression model
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)


y_test_prediction=model.predict(X_test)
```

this link is my error:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUp00.png)

Comment: Show some code!! In which code line this error occurs?

Comment: I put a piecce of my code ,for my reputation is not enough, the picture cannot show

Comment: What is 1*688? num_features*num_samples?

Comment: I am not getting any error on random arrays of your given shape. What version of scikit are you using?

Comment: my scikit-learn is 0.17.1 in anaconda

Comment: I update scikit-learn to the latest 0.18  but it doesn't work

Comment: make sure all your data objects, like X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test are of same type. ie array or matrix. Please read the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028991/numpy-dot-dimensions-not-aligned)

Comment: Kumar thanks, I have fixed my problem .All my data type is int16. The error occurs because I misuse the 'reshape(-1,1)'method with my X_test and Y_test data, I think  my  X_data be 1*688, but  in reality is 688*1, I change 'reshape(-1,1)' to 'reshape(1,-1)', All things right !!!