# Numpy.Python Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python. I am trying to read the image into array and perform SVD(step1). Then multiply SVD with the original array(step2) . In step 2 , which is highlighted in bold below I get an error "shapes(10,1024) and (640,1024) are not aligned:1024(dim 1) ! = 640(dim 0).Any help is much appreciated.

```
# Import sample.png into array img as command parameter
      img = scipy.misc.imread(inputfile)
      print(img.shape)

# Perform SVD on im and obtain individual matrices
      P, D, Q = numpy.linalg.svd(img, full_matrices=False)

# Compute overall SVD matrix based on individiual matrices
      svd_decomp = numpy.dot(numpy.dot(P, numpy.diag(D)), Q)

 # Keep Top entries in svd_decomp
      initial = svd_decomp.argsort()
      temp = numpy.array(initial)
      svd_final = numpy.argpartition(temp,-rank)[-rank:]
      print (svd_final.shape)

 # Multiply to obtain the best rank-k approximation of the original array 
 #numpy.dot(svd_decomp * img)
 #print (svd_final.dot(img))
     print(numpy.dot(svd_final,img))**
```

Comment: Well what is not clear about it? You can only multiply two matrices if the number of columns of the first matrix is equal to the number of rows of the second one.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028991/numpy-dot-dimensions-not-aligned

Comment: Thanks Williem and Sharatpc , I was able to transpose and solve the issue .

Comment: # Multiply to obtain the best rank-k approximation of the original array 
img = numpy.transpose(img)
final = (numpy.dot(svd_final,img))